# Asp: Cannot get the value of a radio button?

Tags: asp.net

I want to retrieve the value of a radio button from a form located in an ASP page "paiment.asp" and display it into another ASP page "confirm.asp"
So, I used:

```
<input type=radio name="type" id="trim" checked=checked value="trim"/>
<input type=radio name="type" id="Radio2" value="sem" />
<input type=radio name="type" id="Radio3" value="annuel"/>
```

and this code into the page confirm                    `

```
<%
    string ab="";
    if (Request.Form["type"] != null)
    {
        ab = Request.Form["type"].ToString();
    }
%>

<% =ab %>
```

but I didn't get any result.Is there something wrong?
`

Comment: What does your form look like?

Comment: You claim to use asp-classic, but the code seems to be ASP.NET. Which one is it?

Comment: <form id="CompanyForm" name="CompanyForm" method="post" action="../Paiement/confirmationpaiement">

Comment: ASP.net.. I'm affraid it's not asp-classic

Comment: @David Going off your edit I wouldn't say it's obvious it's ASP.Net. Classic ASP can run `JavaScript` code by switching the [`@Language` Processing Directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524311(v=vs.90).aspx) to `"javacript"`. In this case though the strongly typed variables like `string ab="";` give it away as c# and ASP.Net.

Comment: @Lankymart I would still say it´s very unlikely to be JavaScript as JavaScript  don't use `<% %>`. But I do agree with you somewhat as the code seems like a mixture of classic ASP and .NET.

Comment: If it's asp.Net why are you using an .asp file? ASP.Net files are .aspx. You also originally tagged this as MVC. **What technology are you using?**

Comment: @David It does when it's used as the Scripting Engine for Classic ASP.

Comment: @Lankymart :) of course!  (I need more coffee)

Comment: @David You and me both fella ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just checked the below code in fiddler:

```
    <html> 
     <head></head> 
     <body> 
      <form method="post">
        <input type="radio" name="group1" id="serviceDaily" value="Daily">  Daily </input> 
        <input type="radio" name="group1" id="serviceWeekly" value="Weekly">  Weekly</input> 
        <input type="radio" name="group1" id="serviceMonthly" value="Monthly">  Monthly</input> 
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
      </form>
      </div> 
     <%
      Dim group1
       group1 = Request("group1") 
       Response.Write ("group1='" + group1 + "'")
     %>
   </body> 
   </html>
```

Hope the above helps you :)

Answer (score -1):

You're forgetting the **runat="server"** attribute. Without it, the state is not transferred between the client and server.

Comment: This isn't ASP.Net it's classic ASP. The Op had mis-tagged it

Comment: My bad - Then check your form tags. If the inputs are not in the submitted form, it won't be passed to the server in the request

Comment: Julian are you talking about : <asp:Content ID="Main" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server"> ?

Comment: No - if i recall correctly, only controll's with the runat="server" attribute is included in the viewstate, even if parent controll's has the attribute... In ASP.Net at least - I've never worked with classic ASP, but I'm guessing that uses plain old html forms...

Comment: @liam According to the OP it is ASP.Net **not** Classic ASP.

Comment: I guess I'm still a bit out of my element here - If i had to go back to asp.net, I'd make it an aspx-file, and address the "type" radiobuttons directly in the eventhandler for the submit-button - which would require the state to be synced via the viewstate, hence the runat="server" attribute...

Comment: I tried also: if (Request.QueryString["type"] != null) { // ab = Request.Form["type"].ToString(); ab = Request.QueryString["type"].ToString(); } but it does not work neither

Comment: Welcome back, I got it now, in fact the problem was in the previous page, the button was not a submit button.It was just an <input type="button" > I swiched it to submit and it works fine :)